# SSRS export to Excel force number to be a text value

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services

Using SSRS

All the other questions are how to force the number to show as a number instead of text when exporting to Excel

Meanwhile I want to force the number to show as a text so that Excel does not turn number 6158.30 to 6158.285 which is causing me round up issues.

My SQL uses cast to 2 decimal places `CAST(ROUND(Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2))`, in Excel it shows as 6158.30 but when you click on the cell its showing 6158.285.

I have tried concatenating ' + value but it exports the data as 'value and NOT force the cell to show as a text data.

Comment: I think your question should be 'why isn't my query rounding my result'. Do you see 6158.285 if you run the report query designer?

Comment: The base query/dataset pulls the data as CAST(ROUND(Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2)) but as I need to multiply the result by 148.5 the result comes out to 3 decimal places. I use SSRS to display the number to 2 decimal places, but when it is exported to Excel it retains the 3 decimals and then the calculations are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to try to turn the number into text, when all you are trying to do is to prevent the number displaying with more than 2 decimal places in Excel.

From the behavior you have described, it sounds like that for the textbox, you are currently using an SSRS expression like:

```
=Fields!Net.Value * 148.5
```

and using the Format property of the textbox to display to 2 decimal places.

Instead, for the SSRS expression, try:

```
=Round(Fields!Net.Value * 148.5, 2)
```

No need to set the textbox's Format property (unless you want commas etc).
Then that textbox column should stay as a number to 2 decimal places, when the report is generated to Excel, and the cell selected.

Comment: Thank you, although I didn't use your formula it was pretty much the same concept. I used SQL to cast the resultant calculation.